# How does sliding window work in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'd like to understand how the spark structured streaming windowing aggregation function works.

Let's say, I have my data arriving with a rate of 1 record/s.

If I use a `groupBy("timestamp", 1 hours, 1 minutes)` I would expect that, every "1 minutes" spark aggregates the data that has arrived in past "1 hours". 
Then, I write my output on eventhubs, and if I use a trigger processingTime of, say, 1 minutes, I have my output every 1 minutes.

The result that I get is that every 1 minutes, I don't get only one window of the aggregation for the past hour, but I get several windows in the past.

The code I used is the following:

```
 streamingDF\
         .groupBy(
            window("timestamp", "1 hours", "1 minutes") \
         ).agg((F.collect_set(F.col("users"))).alias("array")) \
         .writeStream \
         .format("eventhubs") \
         .queryName("query_output") \
         .options(**createEhConf(secretScope, secretEhOutputProcessing)) \
         .outputMode("complete") \
         .trigger(processingTime="1 minutes") \
         .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/dbkcheckpoint/checkpoints/eventhub/output_query/v1") \
         .start()
```

How can I get, every 1 minute, the data that arrived in the past hour only (so, only one window)?

I tried setting the sliding window with the same length of the window, and it outputs me only one window, but I don't think this is the right way to achieve what I want.

Any help?

Comment: Before I answer your question, let me ask you another - how would you define the past in _"the data that has arrived in past "1 hours""_? What's the notion of time? Are you interested in batch time or event time? Both are possible.

Comment: I don't know how to answer to your question, but I can try. 

Let's suppose our starting time is called t0. 
The sensor sends me messages, and every message I receive I have to process all the data arrived since t0.
When we reach t0 + 8h, I need to erase all the data, and start again with a new t0. 
Did I answer to your question?

Comment: Do messages have this `t0` as part of their payload? Can you show a sample message?

Comment: My message is the following: 

timestamp                                        id
2020-01-07T09:44:18.000+0000 123456

Comment: Hi Jared, basically the question is how to process only the data arrived in the last X minutes. 
How can I achieve this?  Thank you